# Leviticus 25:46 meaning of Israelite brethren

Tags: leviticus

Leviticus 25:46 (*KJV*):

> And ye shall take them as an inheritance for your children after you, to inherit *them for* a possession; they shall be your bondmen for ever: but over your brethren the children of Israel, ye shall not rule one over another with rigour.

The verses 44 to 46 are concerned with slavery. I was wondering if by Israelite brethren the verse referred to servitude of those who had no debts within Israel and hence no reason to be a bondservant. Therefore a kind of illegal, forced, sinful slavery.

Is this correct? I find it difficult to comprehend why an Israelite who had a debt would be treated any differently from a foreigner in the same position.

Answer (score 1):

A clue is provided to us in Lev 25:55 which states "for the Israelites belong to me as servants. They are my servants, whom I brought out of Egypt. I am the Lord your God."

An understanding of the historical customs surrounding conversion may also be helpful. [Lawrence J. Epstein](http://www.lawrencejepstein.com/wp/about-lawrence-j-epstein/) [writes](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/life/Life_Events/Conversion/History/Ancient.shtml?p=2)

> God was conceived in very early Jewish thought as a national deity,
>   protecting the Israelites in their land, aiding them in their fights,
>   freeing them from hunger, and generally providing for the nation's
>   sustenance. ... God was seen as the exclusive Lord of the
>   Israelites; they could worship no other deity and God would protect no
>   other people.

As such, only by *being* Hebrew could you enjoy the benefits brought by following Yahewh. This did not exclude the foreigner however. Again, Epstein writes:

> While there were no 'conversions,' many non-Israelites joined the
>   Israelite community, often through marriage or acceptance of the
>   beliefs and practices of the community. In this sense, assimilation is
>   the earliest form of conversion. Abraham and his descendants absorbed
>   many pagans and servants into their group, greatly increasing the size
>   of the Israelite people. ...  Some ...wished to join the Israelites.
>   Such people were given a new status, as gerim (Hebrew for
>   "strangers"). A ger would be taken to the holy mountain and there
>   render the necessary sacrifices.
>
> Gerim often assimilated into the Israelite people by intermarriage.
>   For instance, pagan women who married Jewish men automatically adopted
>   their clan, and thus their religious views. The marriages that
>   resulted were seen as positive because pagans would turn from idolatry
>   to God through such marriages.
>
> The gerim were permanent residents, but did not own land. All
>   non-Israelites who joined a family or tribe were to be given equal
>   rights and equal responsibilities, although the participation in
>   religious rituals developed in stages. The Israelites were enjoined to
>   love the gerim, for the Israelites had been gerim in Egypt.

Presumably then, after adopting Israelight nationality and religeon, a foreigner was no longer different than their new Israelite bretheren and were entitled to the same rights to not be a slave.

This then is no different than Salvation - it is a right available to everyone, but only through fully adopting Yahweh as your God.